# How to prevent deadlock when updating product attribute?

Tags: magento2, database, product-attribute, deadlock

I have built a seperate module for my ERP and custom import from excel file to update product attribute. These two modules using this Magento function to update product attribute:

```
/* Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action */
$this->productAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attrData, $storeId);
```

all has been running smoothly until these 2 functions running around the same time and probably processing the same product, and i'm starting to have these kind of errors

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`,`updated_at`) VALUES (?, '2022-01-21 06:50:07') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `updated_at` = VALUES(`updated_at`)

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT  INTO `magcatalog_product_entity_decimal` (`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`

is there a way to prevent this deadlock from happening ?

Comment: This issue because of the reindxing. it not properly reindexed so to fix this issue reset the reindex using command. 
 
bin/magento indexer:reset 

Then run the reindex command : 

bin/magento indexer:reindex 

Once reindex is done. please try to import the csv file it will work properly. or You can try to solve it by increasing the innodb_lock_wait_timeout MySQL parameter’s value, but the best solution would be to optimize your script to avoid such locks.